# Set SQL Server Agent job to run hourly at specific time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a job I want to create that will run once an hour.

However, I want this job to run at HH:58, not HH:00.

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify this in the schedule details.

Am I missing something or can this not be specified for jobs?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: just change the start time to 12:58, or 11:58 if that suites it better. The "every hour" will calculate based off this seed.

Comment: So start time at 12:58 AM and ending at 11:58:59 PM?  A little confused as I don't want it to miss an hour based off of the ending at parameter

Comment: I'd start it at 1158 PM and end it at 1157 PM or 1258AM start and 1257 AM end. Just make the end 1 second less than your start.

Comment: Ok, will give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: what if the machine reboots at 3am?  Will that interrupt the schedule?